# Macbook Pro 2013 no longer boots

Tags: macbook-pro

My MacBook Pro 2013 no longer boots. I've tried different modes like safe boot, utility menu, boot from other device,... but I instantly get a white screen. Wiping the NVRAM, removing the battery or the SSD does not work.

Has anyone an idea what I can do or how I can reflash the firmware maybe this will solve my problem?

Comment: is there something that makes you think this is a firmware problem?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204156 has multiple possible reasons listed for startup screens.

Comment: I've been working on Macs since System 6. I have **NEVER** heard of firmware flashing as an acceptable troubleshooting step. Note even sure where you would get one outside of having the equipment to get it out of the Mac itself.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. 
@ankiiiiiii: There is only a white/gray screen without any logo,...

I just thought if I didn't go to bios, boot menu,... it could be due to the firmware.

Answer (score 1):

the only thing left no removed  - try removing RAM modules one at a time ( try each sodimm individually in either slot - do not forget to power unit off ( fans not spinning) as you meddle inside the unit ;) ... 
also - did you disconnect the dvd drive and did you inspect the logic board for possible water damage?

by the look - the unit does not pass POST  either due to dGPU or RAM/northbridge

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I can't remove the RAM, it's built-in. I've already tried to remove the battery and press the power button to discharge everything.

I don't think it's a water damage. I've shutdown the macbook, during the shutdown the current was removed. Next day the macbook does not boot any more. Pressing D to perform some hardware checks is also not working.

Comment: then the unit  must be macbook pro **RETINA** -- is it the one with a discreet GPU ? ( then it's most likely cause) - Apple had a customer satisfaction replacemet programme replacing those.

Comment: right now the most likely easy way is to have main board replaced :(

Comment: any chance of testing what an external monitor does? (no pic, the same gray whote screen, something different)

Comment: yes, it's a a1502 with retina. I cannot find the replacement program on there homepage: https://support.apple.com/exchange_repair
I also think the motherboard is broken. External monitor, no changes, I've already tried it.